# Examples of Diff iPhone development program

Tags: iphone

tell me the examples of both the iPhone development programs.

1)Standard Program

and

2)Enterprise Program

==>is Enterprise program == Intranet App -using which we can provide limited access within the company employees

==>and Standard program == Internet App -using which we can provide the access to all iphone users worldwide using iTunes.

am i correct or not ?

please correct me if i am wrong...

Thanking you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enterprise only allows in-house distribution, and Standard only allows AppStore distribution.

See this chart for detail:

http://developer.apple.com/programs/iphone/enterprise/#compare

Comment: Hi Kenny
thanks for replying...
I have already seen thatBut i want to know example App of that two prog
if you know any ?

Comment: @yakub: all AppStore apps are from the standard program. No one knows any enterprise apps because that's for private distribution only.